# How can I see where my memory is being allocated?

Tags: android, memory, screen-orientation

Here is my issue, if I want the OS to handle the screen rotation, my stack trace tells me I'm out of memory after two or three rotations, then the app crashes with no exception or any real trace. Obviously, I'm out of memory, but I have no idea where the leak is. How can I figure this out? The Application starts just fine and runs perfectly (and quickly) up until I rotate it.

Any suggestions or clues?

Thanks ~Aedon

```
 107           WindowManager  I  Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=0
  107         ActivityManager  I  Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/120 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=167}
  107              UsageStats  I  Unexpected resume of com.android.appion.arm.activities while already resumed in com.android.appion.arm.activities
 29574      AppionApplication  I  alive? com.android.appion.arm.widgets.Workspace@45fa1d08
 29574               dalvikvm  D  GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 347 objects / 20712 bytes in 101ms
  107       WimaxStateTracker  D  GetAvailableMs
  107                dalvikvm  D  GC_EXPLICIT freed 11672 objects / 643080 bytes in 123ms
  107       WimaxStateTracker  D  GetAvailableMs
  107           WindowManager  I  Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=0
  107         ActivityManager  I  Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/120 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=2 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=168}
  107              UsageStats  I  Unexpected resume of com.android.appion.arm.activities while already resumed in com.android.appion.arm.activities
 29574      AppionApplication  I  alive? com.android.appion.arm.widgets.Workspace@45fa1d08
 29574               dalvikvm  D  GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 408 objects / 21464 bytes in 84ms
  107                dalvikvm  D  GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 488 objects / 40864 bytes in 157ms
  107                dalvikvm  D  GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 32 objects / 1608 bytes in 142ms
  107                dalvikvm  D  GC_EXPLICIT freed 242 objects / 11288 bytes in 117ms
  107           WindowManager  I  Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=0
  107         ActivityManager  I  Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/120 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=169}
  107       WimaxStateTracker  D  GetAvailableMs
  107              UsageStats  I  Unexpected resume of com.android.appion.arm.activities while already resumed in com.android.appion.arm.activities
 29574      AppionApplication  I  alive? com.android.appion.arm.widgets.Workspace@45fa1d08
 29574          dalvikvm-heap  E  4320000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
 29574               dalvikvm  E  Out of memory: Heap Size=4867KB, Allocated=2497KB, Bitmap Size=15657KB
 29574            GraphicsJNI  E  VM won't let us allocate 4320000 bytes
 28665                  DEBUG  I  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 28665                  DEBUG  I  Build fingerprint: 'sprint/htc_supersonic/supersonic/supersonic:2.2/FRF91/294884:user/release-keys'
 28665                  DEBUG  I  pid: 29574, tid: 29574  >>> com.android.appion.arm.activities <<<
 28665                  DEBUG  I  signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   r0 002a7348  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 002a736c
 28665                  DEBUG  I   r4 002a7348  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   r8 bee47130  r9 41873724  10 41873710  fp bee47478
 28665                  DEBUG  I   ip 002a7348  sp bee46ef8  lr 00000000  pc ab14b0e4  cpsr 60000010
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d0  6472656767756265  d1  6f6c6c6120737562
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d2  6f6f74206e6f6979  d3  6620656772616c74
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d4  0000000044610000  d5  4448000044610000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d6  3fc000003fc00000  d7  4080000080000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d8  0000038444961000  d9  0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d16 0000000045fada68  d17 bff0000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d18 3ff0000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d28 00070008000a0009  d29 0005000500050005
 28665                  DEBUG  I   d30 001f001f001f001f  d31 001f001f001f001f
 28665                  DEBUG  I   scr 60000012
 28665                  DEBUG  I  
 28665                  DEBUG  I           #00  pc 0004b0e4  /system/lib/libskia.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I           #01  pc 0004b1a8  /system/lib/libskia.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I           #02  pc 0006896c  /system/lib/libskia.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I           #03  pc 0006434c  /system/lib/libskia.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I           #04  pc 0004f7c0  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I  
 28665                  DEBUG  I  code around pc:
 28665                  DEBUG  I  ab14b0c4 e1500001 e92d4070 e1a05001 e1a04000 
 28665                  DEBUG  I  ab14b0d4 0a00001a e1a06005 ebffff9f e1a0c004 
 28665                  DEBUG  I  ab14b0e4 e8b6000f e8ac000f e8b6000f e8ac000f 
 28665                  DEBUG  I  ab14b0f4 e8960003 e88c0003 e5950004 e3500000 
 28665                  DEBUG  I  ab14b104 0a000001 e2800004 ebff7655 e5950000 
 28665                  DEBUG  I  
 28665                  DEBUG  I  code around lr:
 28665                  DEBUG  I  
 28665                  DEBUG  I  stack:
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46eb8  afd4372c  /system/lib/libc.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ebc  afd43788  /system/lib/libc.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ec0  002a7340  [heap]
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ec4  00000000  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ec8  bee47130  [stack]
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ecc  41873724  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ed0  41873710  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ed4  afd0c737  /system/lib/libc.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ed8  002a7348  [heap]
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46edc  00000000  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ee0  00000000  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ee4  ab14af6c  /system/lib/libskia.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ee8  002a7348  [heap]
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46eec  00000000  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ef0  df002777  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46ef4  e3a070ad  
 28665                  DEBUG  I  #00 bee46ef8  002a7348  [heap]
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46efc  bee46f5c  [stack]
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46f00  00000000  
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46f04  ab14b1ac  /system/lib/libskia.so
 28665                  DEBUG  I  #01 bee46f08  002a7340  [heap]
 28665                  DEBUG  I      bee46f0c  ab168970  /system/lib/libskia.so
  107            BootReceiver  I  Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
  107         ActivityManager  I  Process com.android.appion.arm.activities (pid 29574) has died.
  107         ActivityManager  W  Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.appion.arm.activities/com.android.appion.arm.core.AppionApplication$IOService in 5000ms
   63                  Zygote  D  Process 29574 terminated by signal (11)
  107         ActivityManager  E  fail to set top app changed!
  107              UsageStats  I  Unexpected resume of com.google.android.gm while already resumed in com.android.appion.arm.activities
```

EDIT:: OnCreate an onResume

```
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
            mApp = (AppionApplication)getApplicationContext();
            if (mApp.getDrawer() == null) {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                Workspace w = (Workspace) li.inflate(R.layout.workspace, null);
                w.setContext(this);
                w.init();
                mApp.setDrawer(w);
            }
            initWidgets();
            AppionApplication a = ((AppionApplication)getApplicationContext());
            mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            determineFirstStart();                
        }



@Override public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.homescreen_main);
    mMain.addView(mApp.getDrawer());
}
```

Comment: Post the code for the Activity which is causing the problem. Include at least onCreate() and onResume().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html
The MAT tool is really helpful in plugging memory leaks.

Comment: I downloaded and ran MAT. I'm not entirely sure I know what I'm looking at. If I understand the report, it says that my app is using on;y 3.16% of the total used resources. I should be far into the clear if this is th case.

Comment: did you dump the HPROF File and load into MAT as explained in the tutorial from abhilash?

Comment: Yes, I have used MAT tool as explained in the blog to analyze out of memory issues. But I personally prefer doing - kill -10 <pid>, then pulling out hprof file from /data/misc, doing hprof-conv and then using Jhat tool.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA - What you should look for is how many instances of your activity are present in memory. There should not be more than one. If there is check where you are leaking the activity context. Usually statics are a suspect.